# Pagination using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller, pagination

I want to display 10 records per page on a spring jsp page using hibernate pagination. I have tried j Query Data table but that is in-memory pagination. I have been trying to implement hibernate pagination but i could not properly connect it with my view page.

Please help me with a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify your query to return chunk of data depending on your page size. For example - if you want to display 10 records then set your pageSize to 10 and send request with pageNumber to fetch records.

Your query look something like this -

```
query.setFirstResult(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1) + 1);
query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
return query.list();
```

Comment: Can you be more elaborate ? As in can you write a small snippet of a jsp page with a table and then how i map this with the table. And also how should i send page number when i click on a page number on the jsp.